# BigQuery api Java NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-bigquery

I’m developing a Java Application with Google App Engine. Therefore, I wanted to show some Data which are stored in Google BigQuery. How can I use the provided APIs to run my App locally in Eclipse?

I have downloaded “gcloud-java-bigquery-0.2.8.jar” and copied this file in WEB-INF/lib. Then I clicked on build path in Eclipse and selected the file.
My Code, which is still very simple, had then no errors in eclipse:

```
import com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQuery;
import com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryOptions;


public class QuickstartSample {
  public static void runBQ(){
      BigQuery bigquery = BigQueryOptions.defaultInstance().getService();

 }
}
```

But when I compile this to run on Google App Engine localy I get:
**"java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/cloud/bigquery/BigQueryOptions"**

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/cloud/bigquery/BigQueryOptions
    at testpackage.dto.QuickstartSample.runBQ(QuickstartSample.java:38)
    at testpackage.getbigquery.doPost(getbigquery.java:27)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:134)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:48)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:122)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:366)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectModuleRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:349)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:116)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:95)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:508)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:547)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryOptions
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.IsolatedAppClassLoader.loadClass(IsolatedAppClassLoader.java:195)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 39 more
```

How can I solve this Problem? Do I need some more jars from google or do I need to modify my .classpath or something else.
I read so many solutions but nothing worked for me yet.
I’m very thankful for every help I can get.

Comment: First of all, I recommend you to use maven or any other build tool. Copying jar files manually is a history. Next, NoClassDefFoundError occur when the class was present at compile time but not at run time. Either your jar is not present at runtime for some reason, or BigQueryOptions is an interface (not sure just assuming) and requires an implementation that is in some other jar. However, if you can both compile and run in eclipse and get error when you deploy, it eliminates second option, and leaves only package as a possible cause.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You were totally right! It was a lot easier to build the project with Maven.

Answer (score 1):

You may have the incorrect JAR.

Please try building your project using Maven and using the latest version of Java BigQuery client library:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>google-cloud-bigquery</artifactId>
  <version>1.111.1</version>
</dependency>
```

All the release BigQuery client artifacts can be found here: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/cloud/google-cloud-bigquery/

Java BigQuery client is open source: https://github.com/googleapis/java-bigquery